# ASP.Net UpdatePanel not Updating, Partial Postback fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

So I've been stuck on this problem for quite a few hours now, searched forums, tried everything people suggest, but i just can't make it work.

I have a (rather large) web form.  Somewhere on the form is an updatePanel which contains a CuteSoft Ajax Uploader control.  That control calls a function in my code behind when a file is uploaded - this works fine.  In that function I make some changes to the content in the updatePanel (add thumbnails etc), however the changes never reflect on the front end.

Here's the form (with irrelevant bits chopped out):

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VehicleSubmissionWizard.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MaxAdmin.UserControls.VehicleSubmissionWizard" %>
...
<div id="template3" style="display: none;">
    <div class="top-section">
        <div id="column-left">
            ...
        <div id="column-right">
            ...
    <form runat="server" id="form1" action="">
    <%--Panel 1--%>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSubmissionWizard1">
        ...
    </asp:Panel>
    <%--/Panel 1--%>
    <%--Panel 2--%>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSubmissionWizard2">
        ...
            <h2>
                Vehicle images</h2>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"
                AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableViewState="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true"
                ScriptMode="Auto" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" EnableViewState="false" ID="upImageUpload" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <Triggers>
                    <%--                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Uploader" 
                           EventName="FileUploaded" />
                    --%>
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <input id="hdnImages" class="imagesUpload" type="hidden" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn" runat="server" />
                    <CuteWebUI:Uploader ID="Uploader" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" MaxFilesLimit="3"
                        MaxFilesLimitMsg="Please upload a maximum of 3 photos" InsertButtonStyle-Width="280px"
                        MultipleFilesUpload="true" InsertText="Upload Photos [Max 3 Photos at up to 4mb each]"
                        OnFileUploaded="Uploader_FileUploaded" OnUploadCompleted="Uploader_Complete">
                        <ValidateOption MaxSizeKB="4096" AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,gif,png" />
                    </CuteWebUI:Uploader>
                    <div id="attachmentsDiv">
                        <CuteWebUI:UploadAttachments EnableViewState="false" runat="server" ID="Attachments"
                            MaxFilesLimit="3" Visible="false">
                            <ValidateOption MaxSizeKB="4096" AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,gif,png" />
                        </CuteWebUI:UploadAttachments>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlImageDetails_1" runat="server" CssClass="display_none" Style="float: left;
                        margin-bottom: 0">
                        <div class="uploadedImage" style="clear: both; float: left; margin: 5px 20px 5px 75px;">
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgUploadedImage1" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveImage_1" runat="server" OnCommand="RemoveImage_Click"
                                    CommandName="1" Text="Remove Image" CssClass="RemoveLinkButton" Style="margin-left: 15px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlImageDetails_2" runat="server" CssClass="display_none" Style="float: left;">
                        <div class="uploadedImage" style="clear: both; float: left; margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;">
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgUploadedImage2" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveImage_2" runat="server" OnCommand="RemoveImage_Click"
                                    CommandName="2" Text="Remove Image" CssClass="RemoveLinkButton" Style="margin-left: 15px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlImageDetails_3" runat="server" CssClass="display_none" Style="float: left;">
                        <div class="uploadedImage" style="clear: both; float: left; margin: 5px 20px 5px 20px;">
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:Image ID="imgUploadedImage3" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRemoveImage_3" runat="server" OnCommand="RemoveImage_Click"
                                    CommandName="3" Text="Remove Image" CssClass="RemoveLinkButton" Style="margin-left: 15px;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                        var Image_Count = $('#<%= hdn.ClientID %>').val(); 
                    </script>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            ...
    </asp:Panel>
    <%-- / Panel 2--%>
    <%--Panel 3--%>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSubmissionWizard3">
        ...
    </asp:Panel>
    <%-- / Panel 3--%>
    <%-- Panel 4--%>
    <asp:Panel Visible="false" runat="server" ID="pnlSubmissionWizard4">
        ...
    </asp:Panel>
    <%-- / Panel 4--%>
    </form>
    ...
</div>
```

The Codebehind looks like this:

...

```
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);

            //Uploader.FileUploaded += new CuteWebUI.UploaderEventHandler(Uploader_FileUploaded);
            Uploader.FileUploaded += Uploader_FileUploaded;
            Uploader.UploadCompleted += Uploader_Complete;
            Attachments.AttachmentRemoveClicked += Attachments_AttachmentRemoveClicked;
            Attachments.InsertButton.Style["display"] = "none";
            ((HiddenField)FindControl("hdn")).Value = "0";
        }

...

        protected void Uploader_FileUploaded(object sender, CuteWebUI.UploaderEventArgs args)
        {
            ...

                using (System.IO.Stream stream = args.OpenStream())
                {
                    // Check if file already exists - seems to do each image twice for some reason...
                    foreach (var ph in Photos)
                        if (String.Equals(ph.FileName, args.FileName))
                            return;

                    ...

                    // Show image thumbnail
                    ShowUploadedPhotoDetails(p, ImageCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ...
            }
        }

    private void ShowUploadedPhotoDetails(Photo photo, int imageNo)
    {
        if (imageNo <= 3)
        {
            var imagePanel = (Panel)FindControl(String.Concat("pnlImageDetails_", imageNo));
            imagePanel.CssClass = "display_block";
            imagePanel.Visible = true;

            var uploadedImage = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)FindControl(String.Concat("imgUploadedImage", imageNo));
            uploadedImage.ImageUrl = photo.ImageUrlThumb;
            uploadedImage.Visible = true;
            uploadedImage.CssClass = "CSS_CLASS";
        }
    }

        protected void Uploader_Complete(object sender, CuteWebUI.UploaderEventArgs[] args)
        {
            Uploader uploader = (Uploader)sender;
            uploader.InsertButton.Enabled = (Photos.Count < 3);

            // Force updatePanel to update
            upImageUpload.Update();
        }
```

So both the above functions fire when an image is uploaded. The image data is coming through fine.  Debugging the values assigned to the controls (eg: ImageUrl, CssClass, etc) shows that they're getting assigned to the controls correctly.. however the values never get refreshed on the front end.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Thanks heaps
Greg

Comment: Perhaps the Uploader_Complete event occurs after the last page event the output can be updated on the screen.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, I got it!!!  Basically I rebuilt the entire form, step by tedious little step.  While I don't know exactly what was stopping it from working, i suspect it may have been caused by the following attributes set on buttons in other parts of the form:

```
PostbackUrl = ".."
```

Adding that back in to my working form causes the updatePanel to break.. but removing it from my original broken form does not fix it, so perhaps there was something else in there too.

No code was changed, so it wasn't anything to do with sequencing of events etc (good idea though TheGeekYouNeed.

This was a project updated from Asp.Net 2.0 to 4.0 .. perhaps something in the upgrade messed it up.  Who knows, anyway at least it's fixed.  PHEW!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any errors inside the UpdatePanel including a div tag not properly formatted, etc. the refresh of the panel may not occur. If you're not getting an UpdatePanel to refresh and you've tried all the usual things .Update() , etc. then check for any issue with the content of your UpdatePanel and it should fix it.